# AD Delegated user password change

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a code in PowerShell that will loop till the user would like to exit. Thus, allowing the delegated user to change passwords for student accounts.

I have tested the code for the password change and it works without any issues.

As soon as I try adding a while loop the code wont run.

```
#Open powershell as Administrator
Start-process Powershell -verb RunAs

# Connect to the Domain Controller
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "" -Credential (Get-Credential)
Invoke-Command $session -Scriptblock { Import-Module ActiveDirectory }
Import-PSSession -session $session -Module ActiveDirectory

#verify that you're connectedto the Domain
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object name

#run Password Change
$userid = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the studnets login ID'
$newPassword = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the studnets new password'

$run = 'yes'
while ($run -eq 'yes')
    {
        if (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $userid})
        {
           Set-ADAccountPassword $userid -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText '$newPassword')
           Write - Host "$userid` password has now been changed to: $newPassword"
        }
        else
        {
            Write - Host "$userid` does not exist, please try again."  
        }
        $answer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Would you like to change another studnets password? [y|n]'
        while ($answer -notcontains 'n' -or $answer -notcontains 'N' -or $answer -notcontains 'y' -or $answer -notcontains 'Y')
        {
             $answer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please answer [y|n]'
        }
        if ($answer -eq 'y' -or $answer -eq 'Y')
        {
            $run = 'yes'
        }
        if ($answer-eq 'n' -or $answer -eq 'N')
        {
            exit
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is not case sensitive by default / design. So, no need to check for that.

Based on what you are after, you have potentially over engineered this item.

I'd suggest changing this to a simple to a Do..Until.

```
Clear-Host
do
{
    "`n"
    $TargetUser = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a user SamAccountName'
    "Processing  user $TargetUser"
    Get-ADUser -Identity $TargetUser
    "`n"
    $answer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Would you like to see another user? [y|n]'    
}
until ($answer -eq 'n')

"You entered $answer. Finished processing routine."

Enter a user SamAccountName: Administrator
Process user Administrator


...
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : 
Name              : Administrator
...
SamAccountName    : Administrator
...

Would you like to see another user? [y|n]: y

Enter a user SamAccountName: sqladmin
Process user sqladmin

...
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : SqlAdmin
Name              : SqlAdmin ServiceAccount
...
SamAccountName    : sqladmin
...

Would you like to see another user? [y|n]: n
You entered n. Finished processing routine.
```

Personally, if it were me doing this, I'd approach this a different way.

1. Create file on a share that can be updated with user SamAccountName
   / ID's for target changes.
2. Read in that file in the code.
3. In the code, auto generate a password.
4. Do whatever additional steps as needed in the code.

Thus removing all the manual prompting labor.